# Hiding/Showing border

Tags: html, css

Today I was trying to create a card in HTML/CSS with hidden border which appears after hovering on a card. I came up with this code, which works fine for me:

```css
.card
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  background-color: red;
}

.card:hover
{
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

I just want to know if there isn't any better way of doing this. This works fine since I don't need to animate it, but is this a proper way of hiding border or not? Thanks for Your answers.

EDIT: I think I should edit my question since I don't want to use `box-sizing: border-box` property. I'd like to hide my border with "content-box". And here `border: none` won't work.

Comment: you can use `border:none` instead `border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is the right way to handle this problem.

Others have commented that to hide the border you should use `border: 0px` or `border: none` but with that method you have the problem that when the box is hovered, the width of the element changes making it, not only ugly to look at, but hard to predict what the width will be, and how it can affect adjacent elements.

I would use exactly the same method you have used.

Comment: Exactly my problem here! I can't afford wider card and both of these solutions do that. Thanks for Your answer, I can continue now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also adjust the `background-clip` to avoid the border to overlap the background:

```css
.card
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  background-color: red;
  background-clip:padding-box;
}

.card:hover
{
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

Comment: That's actually really good thing to know. For some reason it does this on my card without applying background-clip, will need to take a look what's the reason. Thanks!

Comment: @Dano probably the background is applied to an inner element ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
.card{
    border: 0px solid black;
}
.card:hover{
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

I think that is your solve

Comment: Well, not really. I've tried doing that, but it changes whole layout, since You have 10px wider card after hovering. If I'd have my card sized as "border-box", this could do that, but I don't want to use "border-box" property. Thanks for Your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**To hide `border` use [`border:none`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) instead `border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);`**

When you use `border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);` means you apply border but with `transparent` `color`.

```css
.card
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.card:hover
{
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: This is basically the same answer as above with different apporach. border: none and border: 0 do the same (I guess) and this will change the layout of my page since my card will be 10px wider and taller after hovering. Edited my question so it's clear. Anyway, thhanks for Your answer!